# How to use would like in my sentences

Tags: sentence-structure, will-would

Sometimes I need to use would like in my sentences, to show some suggestion or asking for something. I really do not how to use it correctly here.

For example, I would like to ask someone whether he/she would like to explain to me something which will help me to understand them. I would like to say this in a more respectable way.

For example,

> If you would like to explain to me what parts that need to be revised it would be very helpful.

Do I  use *would like*  correctly in my sentences.?

Comment: While your sentence is polite enough, it's more polite to tell someone that this is something you would like, rather than basing it on what they would like, *"I would like it very much if you could explain what parts need to be revised"*

Comment: *"If you would like"* is more polite when suggesting options for someone else's comfort or convenience, *"If you would like I could have your supper ready in a few minutes?"*  Asking someone if they would like to help you can sometimes feel more like a *demand* than a *request*.