# How to properly use 'would like to' in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

How to properly say this sentence?

> Open the terminal to the folder you would like to use.

Should I say *you **would like to** use*? or *you **want to** use*?

I learned in one of the comments of this [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162399/how-to-use-would-like-in-my-sentences) that **"would like"** is use to make the sentence sound more politely. But in my case the sentence that I made doesn't need to be sound politely. But **"would like"** to use sounds fine to me than **"want to"**

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct and are almost identical, but there is a subtle distinction:

*"**would like to**" implies that there is some doubt.*

*"**want to**" implies more certainty.*

Comment: I would like to see a supporting reference. Did that leave any doubt?

Comment: In this case, it depicts more polite form of sentence.